# How to install XDebug with Eclipse PDT and XAMPP

Tags: eclipse, xampp, xdebug

Can someone please tell me How can I install **XDebug** and integrate it with my existing XAMPP and Eclipse PDT. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

[This site](http://robsnotebook.com/php_debugger_pdt_xdebug) goes through a very thorough installation process. It says how to install XDebug, and how to integrate it with Eclipse. The only miss, however, is the php.ini configuration. If you use the one it gives you, XDebug will not be loaded properly. I would suggest this:

```
[XDebug]
;; Only Zend OR (!) XDebug
; Modify the filename below to reflect the .dll version of your xdebug
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.1-5.3-vc9.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost  ; if debugging on remote server,
                      ; put client IP here
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "xdebug_profile.%R::%u"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```